# adding toolbar at backend of joomla component

Tags: joomla

i added this toolbar in my component

```
JToolBarHelper::addNew('dropdown.add');
```

when click on the new button by default this controller called.
contollers
          dropdown.php
and in the dropdown file search for dropdownControllerdropdown class and call this class.
but i want to change this default behavior.how to make when user click on the add button componnent go to dropdown.php file and call helloworldControllerdropdown class instead of dropdownControllerdropdown class ???

Answer (score 1):

In your dropdown php try to modify:

```
require_once('helloworld.php');

class DropdownControllerDropdown extends HelloWorldControllerDropdown
```

In this case when method `add` is called it will use `HelloWorldControllerDropdown` method `add` if it's not defined in `DropdownControllerDropdown`

Comment: your answer is usefull.but i have a problem.when HelloWorldControllerDropdown is called com_Dropdown componnent loaded.but i want load com_helloworld componnet.how to do this??

Comment: can you explain why do you need this? Why to use another extension for adding content?